# Summarizing blocks of contiguous dates into start and end dates

Tags: sql, date, output, grouping, date-range

I have a database (SQL 2014) that contains the following entries:

```
Name   Date
John   02/02/2017
John   03/02/2017
John   04/02/2017
John   13/03/2017
John   14/03/2017
```

These entries represent blocks of absences from work - it could be just one day each time, or blocks of several days (with possible month transitions within a block).

I'd like to summarize this data as follows:

```
Name   MinDate     MaxDate
John   02/02/2017  04/02/2017
John   13/03/2017  14/03/2017
```

where the output contains the first and last day of each block (together with the number of days absent, which will be straightforward).

Comment: Your logic is not clear.  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Please clarify the logic. Is it one row per block of contiguous dates (02-04 Feb, 13-14 March)? Or is it min/max per month? Could there more than one such block per month?

Comment: Also it's considered nice to show what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Use `YEAR` and `MONTH`

```
SELECT
    T.Name,
    MIN(T.Date) MinDate,
    MAX(T.Date) MaxDate
FROM
    Tbl T
GROUP BY
    T.Name,
    YEAR(T.Date),
    MONTH(T.Date)
```